# Get path of selected Windows Explorer file in AutoIt

Tags: windows-7-x64, autoit

My AutoIt script worked as long as I used it via command line. There I could use `$CmdLine[1]` and pass a path as argument. Now I try to convert the script to a new method to avoid command line arguments.

You open an Explorer Window and select a file e.g `C:\test.txt`. After that you trigger the AutoIt function with **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>**. The script should look what file is selected in the active Explorer Window and retrieve the path `C:\test.txt` and assign it to `$file` variable.

This is my work-in-progress where I'm stuck.
Line 5 `$CmdLine[1]` needs to be changed to a secret function I don't know.

```
;Assign key combination "CTRL-WIN-C" to function "copyUNC"
HotKeySet("^#c", "CopyUNC") 

;function to copy UNC path of selected Windows Explorer file/folder to clipboard
func CopyUNC()
    $file = FileGetLongName($CmdLine[1])   ;THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
    $drive = StringLeft($file, 2)
    $UNCdrive = DriveMapGet($drive)
    If $UNCdrive = "" Then  
        $UNCfile = $file    
    else 
        $UNCfile = $UNCdrive & StringTrimLeft($file, 2)
    endif   
    ClipPut($UNCfile)
endfunc

;necessary loop so AutoIt script stays active and in Tray
While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
```

**Q:** How do I get the path of a selected file/folder from Windows Explorer into [AutoIt v3.3.8.1](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/)?

*Note #1:* I don't want to use registry and right-click tricks to pass the argument
*Note #2:* If multiple files are selected just pass the first file. Don't overcomplicate things

Comment: As an alternative, you could make your program callable from the "send-to" context menu.  So that you'd right click on the file, select send to, and then your application.  The file would the be passed to your application as cmdline[1]

Comment: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/89833-windows-explorer-current-folder/

Answer (score 1):

CMDLINE[1] has nothing to do with  what you want.

If you want to activate your script by hotkey AFTER manually selecting the file in Windows Explorer, you need to examine the Explorer window itself.

Here is the function to retrieve selected item in explorer

```
Func GetExplorerSelection()
Local $saveClip = ""
Local $filesFolders = ""
Local $handle = _WinAPI_GetForegroundWindow()
Local $className = _WinAPI_GetClassName($handle)
If $className = "ExploreWClass" Or $className = "CabinetWClass" Then
$saveClip = ClipGet()
Send("^c")
Sleep(50) ; give clipboard time to react
$filesFolders = ClipGet()
ClipPut($saveClip)
; test if $filesFolders contains @LF and split if so etc..
; code to call StringSplit() etc..
EndIf
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this

```
HotKeySet('{F8}','ccc')
Func ccc()
$ObjWindows = ObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows()
For $i = 0 To $ObjWindows.Count -1
        Local $w = $ObjWindows.Item($i)
        Local $aSeLected = $w.Document.SelectedItems()
        For $b = 0 To $aSeLected.Count -1
                $x = $aSeLected.Item($b)
                MsgBox(0,'',$x.Path&'_______'&$x.Name)
        Next
Next
EndFunc
While 1
        Sleep(100)
WEnd
```